# GA: Source and medium are not tracked correctly

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have created a Google Ads campaign and for all the url's I have defined an standard url to track them. These url are for example: http://www.example.com/?url_source=s1&utm_medium=m1&utm_campaign=c1. I use this page https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/ to create them.

But, when I go to Acquisition > All the traffic > Source/Medium I see that most of these url are not tracked correctly and are tracked like google/cpc and not with the values given in variables utm_source and utm_medium

What happen? How can I do to track correctly all the url's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use autotagging in Google Ads. You need to allow manual tagging (UTM values) to override auto-tagging in Property Settings in GA. Otherwise in *Acquisition > All the traffic > Source/Medium* you will see douplicated strings.

Comment: Do you know what is the admin option exactly? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I have found it!!! I have checked the option. And now, I have to wait if all the access are tracked correctly :) Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: @JoséCarlos successfully?

Comment: It seems that yes. I have follow some Source/Medium from live stats and I have not saw google/cpc anymore. At the end of the day I will check finally if works fine.

Comment: Hi @zborovskaya!!! I have checked the values of Source/Medium and it works!!! ... But not always :((( And I don't understand because there is still 6 users which appears with google/cpc like Source/Medium :((( But the rest works fine. By the way, I have another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58385635/ga-report-with-transactions-doesnt-show-all-of-them/ It's about Google Data Studio. If you can help me I will apreciate it too!!! And if you cannot help me I will appreciate it equally. :)